# How to construct a xpath expression with variable for Selenium in python using %s

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I am trying to use selenium to locate and select a certain element based on a variable passed into the function when it is called. I thought this would be simple enough with a good ol:

```
show = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % eventName)
```

However, I receive error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(text(), 'VARIABLE_TEXT')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(text(), 'VARIABLE_TEXT')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Here is--distilled and simplified--the part of the HTML I am attempting to select:

```
<ul>
<li class="seriesElement">
<input id="productionId_0" name="productionIds" type="checkbox" value="VALUE"><input type="hidden" name="_productionIds" value="on"><label for="productionId_0" class="prodColor0">TEXT</label>
</li>
<li class="seriesElement">
<input id="productionId_1" name="productionIds" type="checkbox" value="VALUE"><input type="hidden" name="_productionIds" value="on"><label for="productionId_1" class="prodColor1">TEXT</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

There are many of these list elements, and I want to select one by the text. Have I just used the wrong syntax for my xpath expression, or is this a different beast entirely?

Comment: Have you tried building your string first?
searchBy = "//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % eventName
show = browser.find_element_by_xpath(searchBy)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.See if this helps.

```
VAR_TEXT="TEXT"
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text() ,'" + VAR_TEXT + "')]").text)
```

OR

```
VAR_TEXT="TEXT"
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text() ,'" + VAR_TEXT + "')]").text)
```

OR

```
VAR_TEXT="TEXT"
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()[contains(.,'" + VAR_TEXT + "')]]").text)
```

OR

```
VAR_TEXT="TEXT"
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + VAR_TEXT + "')]]").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate a certain element based on it's variable text you can write a method as follows:

- Using **`.`**:

  ```
  def find_myelement_with_text(myString):
      show = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.='" + myString + "']")
  ```
- Using **`%s`**:

  ```
  def find_myelement_with_text(myString):
      show = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), '%s')]" % (myString))
  ```
- Using **`format()`**:

  ```
  def find_myelement_with_text(myString):
      show = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(), "{}")]'.format(myString))
  ```

Now you can call this method from anywhere within your program as follows:

```
find_myelement_with_text("TEXT")
```

Answer (score 0):

The good ol'  `%s` worked as expected - you can see the substitution in the error message, the problem is with the xpath itself.
 If you run it through a standalone parser (not the browser's one), you'll see the culprit for the error:

> Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ("", "", ...)

*(that's a Java one, the text will be similar for other ones)*

Long story short it's the output of `text()` that bothers it - it's a nodeset; if you change that function to a `.`, it should work:

```
show = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., '%s')]" % eventName)
```

Comment: Eh, it turned out to be an issue because the string I was trying to pass had an apostrophe in it. If I take out the xpath runs, but doesn't find the right element because the string is wrong. So I just need to figure out how to pass a string variable with an apostrophe in it. Having trouble... even with escape symbol \, but we'll  see...